# Creating Mile Posts

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to create mile post on a polyline.  I'm getting confused on the LRS.  Can someone assist me? I've tried going through the Linear Referencing Tools in ArcCatalog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Make Route Event Layer Tool to create points along the polyline.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/linear-ref-toolbox/make-route-event-layer.htm

Or with arcpy you can use positionAlongLine method on a Polyline.

positionAlongLine (value, {use_percentage}).

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm